# Structs inside Structs in sequence

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I wanna do a program about blackjack game, but i am trying of a different way, but i don't know if is possible.
The code is compiled but when start the program, it closes:

blackjack.exe has stopped working
A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_PLAYERS 6
#define NUMBER_SUITS 4
#define NUMBER_RANKS 13
#define NUMBER_CARDS (NUMBER_SUITS * NUMBER_RANKS)

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct
{
    uint suit;
    uint rank;
} Card;

typedef struct card
{
    Card card;
    struct card *next;
} card;

typedef struct match
{
    card *list;
    struct match *next;
} Match;

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    uint wins;
    uint losses;
    Match *match;
} Player;

void main(void)
{
    Player player[NUMBER_PLAYERS];
    uint i, j, count = 0;
    char *op;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s%*c", &player[i].name);
        printf("\n\n");
        player[i].losses = 0;
        player[i].wins = 0;
        player[i].match->next = NULL;
        player[i].match->list->next = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I suppose it gives you an error message?  What error message is it?

Comment: Using both `card` and `Card` for type names is likely to cause confusion.  I strongly recommend renaming `card` to something like `CardList`. Since you don't allocate space for `player[i].match` to point at, all operations within the loop on `player[i].match` are undefined behaviour and a program crash is a plausible response.

Comment: I had put this name 'CarList' before, but I changed for leave clearer: player->match->card->suit, I back to CardList again. My principal problem is that I don't know use a struct inside structure inside other structure inside other structure. This seems half nonsense for me. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Player *player[NUMBER_PLAYERS];  // it's an array of pointers,
```

-> Any item in the array needs to point to a Player before you use it

```
    typedef struct match
{
    card *list;                  // it's a pointer
    struct match *next;
} Match;
```

-> card *list is also needs to point to an initialized card

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUMBER_PLAYERS 6

typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct
{
    uint suit;
    uint rank;
} Card;

typedef struct card
{
    Card card;
    struct card *next;
} card;

typedef struct match
{
    card *list;
    struct match *next;
} Match;

typedef struct
{
    char *name;
    uint wins;
    uint losses;
    Match *match;
} Player;

void main(void)
{
    Player player[NUMBER_PLAYERS];
    card cardList[NUMBER_PLAYERS];
    uint i;
    for(i = 0; i < NUMBER_PLAYERS; i++)
    {
        player[i] = NULL;
        printf("Name: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s%*c", &player[i].name);
        printf("\n\n");
        player[i].name;
        player[i].losses = 0;
        player[i].wins = 0;
        player[i].match->next = NULL;
        player[i].match.list = &cardList[i];
        player[i].match.list->next = NULL;
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: I don't understand yet how do work. Has few time that I started with pointers, but thanks for help. Maybe think another way more easy for do this.

Answer (score 1):

Q: Why not just `Player player[NUMBER_PLAYERS];`?  Why a pointer to an array, instead of just an array?

SUGGESTION: Change to `scanf("s%", player[i]->name);`  I assume all you want is to input the name, correct?

SUGGESTION: Create one or more "init_xxx)" functions to initialize your structure (including substructures and/or link pointers) as needed.

Q: What is `player[i]->name;` supposed to do?  Why not just delete that line?

Q: What do you mean by "when start the program, it close: This program has stop working..."?  I notice you have a "getchar()" - does it skip right past getchar()" and terminate?  Does the behavior change when you change the "scanf()"?  Do you get an error message in any case?

Q: What compiler are you using?  Are you on Windows, Linux or "something else"?  Are you using an IDE (like Eclipse/CDT, or Visual Studio)?

Comment: "player[i]->name" I forgot remove it. If remove 'for' block inside main, no error occurs.